# Can metals have both Fracture Toughness and Elasticity properties?

Tags: metal, metallurgy, mechanical-properties

Fracture Toughness is the resistance of a material to cracking and Elasticity is the ability to bend without breaking. I want to know if there is any metal or metal alloy that can easily bend without breaking and still stay strong against force coming towards it and even other materials colliding with it. This could be useful to make safety equipment which protect people and are still not too uncomfortable. (For example a helmet which protects a builder even when sharp bricks fall on it and bends but prevents damage and does not break meaning that sharp pieces wont go inside the person's head, or another example is a place where people can go when there is a natural disaster to stay safe and because of it not fully bending the people who rescue the survivors can see that it is not fully bent meaning that there is someone inside).

Comment: The bending can be useful for things like shaping it back together when it is deformed and so it could also be used for armour which would not take hours to wear.

Comment: What I am saying is that the material only bends and deforms instead of cracking but still absorbs and stops any force that could cause something behind it to be damaged.

Comment: To what extent? Without actual values of what you consider "fracture tough" and "elastic", the question has no meaning.

Comment: Ask a swordsmith?

Comment: There are plenty of varieties of steel (alloys of iron) that combine fracture toughness with a decent amount of elasticity. The control of these properties involve manipulating the material *structure* using processing methods and other ingredients in the alloy. Worth reading JE Gordon's "The New Science of Strong Materials" for lucid overview of the details and history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the one which could be suited for this conditions could be steel. Which is normally an alloy of iron and carbon and have great modulus of elasticity. Even various types of steel are used in making armours. Other options could be osmium, being the densest element it also posses really good elasticity and decent amount of fracture toughness but it's a rare element and so, an expensive choice. So, the best choice is to go with alloys of steel having both  high fracture toughness and great modulus of elasticity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are interested in helmets; modern helmets are all polymer (eg. polycarbonate) or FRP as for as I know. Steel is a "no brainer" for it has high fracture toughness and elasticity. But it may be heavy for a helmet and steel helmets are no longer used in industry because of the electrical shock possibility. I expect this is an OSHA rule.